# Store multiple results from one field in new columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, multiple-columns

Current query returns 3 lines for one invoice if there are 3 denial codes and more if there are multiple denial codes and multiple denial dates. I am trying to create a column for each denial code so all results can be on one line. The requirements from the client is for each denial to be in its own column so I am unable to use the listagg function. 
The results should looks like the below:

office, invoice, denial date, denial code 1, denial code 2, denial code 3, denial date2, denial code 1...etc

Oracle database. Current code:

```
                 SELECT
                 A.OFFICE_NBR,
                 A.INV_NBR,
                 TO_DATE(A.CRTD_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CARC_DT,
                 A.CLM_ID,
                 A.CLM_LN_ID,
                 A.RSN_CD

                 FROM DENIALS A
                 WHERE A.OFFICE_NBR = '1234'
                 AND A.INV_NBR = '123456'
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `PIVOTING`.

Comment: @Rahul I was trying to figure out how to do that but I cant seem to find out how without using an aggregate?

Answer (score 0):

I took a guess at some test data but this should get you going.  Please add some before and after data, that helps a lot to understand what you are trying to do, and allows for building a more realistic solution.

Anyway the caveat is you have to define ahead of time a DENIAL_CD_X column for each possible denial code. I will be interested to see if someone can come up with a dynamic solution for the denial_cd columns.

```
SQL> with DENIALS(OFFICE_NBR, INV_NBR, CRTD_DT, RSN_CD) as (
  2  select '11', '1111', '07/31/2015', '1' from dual
  3  union
  4  select '11', '1111', '07/31/2015', '99' from dual
  5  union
  6  select '11', '1111', '07/31/2015', '50' from dual
  7  union
  8  select '11', '1113', '06/01/2014', '34' from dual
  9  union
 10  select '11', '1113', '06/01/2014', '71' from dual
 11  union
 12  select '32', '3232', '06/21/2015', '34' from dual
 13  union
 14  select '32', '3232', '07/31/2015', '99' from dual
 15  )
 16  select OFFICE_NBR, INV_NBR, TO_DATE(CRTD_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CARC_DT,
 17         DENIAL_CD_1, DENIAL_CD_2, DENIAL_CD_3
 18  from
 19  (
 20    select OFFICE_NBR, INV_NBR, CRTD_DT, rsn_cd,
 21      row_number() over(partition by OFFICE_NBR, INV_NBR, CRTD_DT order by OFFICE_NBR, INV_NBR, CRTD_DT, rsn_cd) rn
 22    from DENIALS
 23  )
 24  pivot
 25  (
 26    max(rsn_cd)
 27    for rn in ('1' as DENIAL_CD_1, '2' as DENIAL_CD_2, '3' as DENIAL_CD_3)
 28  )
 29  order by OFFICE_NBR, INV_NBR, CRTD_DT;

OFFICE_NBR INV_NBR CARC_DT    DENIAL_CD_1 DENIAL_CD_2 DENIAL_CD_3
---------- ------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
11         1111    31-JUL-15  1           50          99
11         1113    01-JUN-14  34          71
32         3232    21-JUN-15  34
32         3232    31-JUL-15  99

SQL>
```